# Magento reviews page template url

Tags: review

Is it possible to use two different layouts for these two review page URL's?

```
http://www.domain.com/laptop1-reviews

http://www.domain.com/review/product/list/id/33661/
```

Both display exactly the same content.

But is it possible to display on one of the two only the reviews and on the other URL only the reviewform?

Comment: yes possible..... will give you full module of your previous question on tomorrow  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69682/load-review-form-on-external-page/70619#70619

Comment: have you check the link.. i was update.  the code

Comment: @AmitBera What is the URL of the review form and the reviews page?

Comment: suppose `linen-blazer-585.html` is product then you can this product review page by suffix add    `-review-form` end of product url ( `linen-blazer-585.html-review-form`)

Comment: @AmitBera Many thanks, but now on this page: linen-blazer-585.html-review-form the entire review form is displayed. So how can I remove the reviews there and only display the review form?

Comment: goto `app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTemplate/template/review/product/view/list.phtml`  and remove all code from where except  `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_form') ?>`

Comment: @AmitBera That removes the reviews also on the 'linen-blazer-585.html-reviews' page. And I want to keep 1 page with reviews and 1 page with only the form.

Comment: @AmitBera I will, but it is not working yet.

Comment: what is the problem...?

Comment: @AmitBera The line you provide removes the reviews also on the 'linen-blazer-585.html-reviews' page. And I want to keep 1 page with reviews and 1 page with only the form.

Comment: Dear jelle, it better to create  new question... it will give you the solution...

Comment: questions is mixed up...

Comment: @AmitBera Why, that was my mean question of this topic. How to split the review form from the review page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you have follow this link [Load review form on external page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69682/load-review-form-on-external-page/70619#70619) for this answe

Now you want to remove from reviews listing whenever try to access using `review page` using `productUrl-review-form`  this type url pattern.

In this set a flag using magento registry variable which tell you the request is coming from  `productUrl-review-form` instead  of `review/product/list/id/33661/`

on class `Dev_Productreview_Controller_Router` add this code

```
Mage::register('review_comming_from',true);
```

**after**

```
$request->setAlias(
                Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                $identifier
        );
```

then fetch the data in

```
app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTemplate/template/review/product/view/list.‌​phtml
```

and check the request is coming from

```
    if(Mage::regsitry('review_comming_from')):
    //coming from custom page
    else:
    // magento default review page
 endif;
```

This condition will help you.