# Magento custom router

Tags: magento-1.9, router

I have a custom module, with an `IndexController` and an `indexAction`. This has a route with a `fronName` set in the `config.xml`(for example `angular-app`). On this page I have an angular app, with it's own routing. Everything works fine until I don't refresh the browser. After refresh I get 404.
How can I setup magento's router to handle every request under the `angular-app` with the `IndexController:indexAction`.

So what I would like:

- request: `http://domain.com/angular-app` -> `IndexController:indexAction`
- request: `http://domain.com/angular-app/x/y/z` -> `IndexController:indexAction` where `x`, `y`, `z` are dynamic parameters.

Comment: Could you share some code? It would make it a little easier to debug

Comment: Sure,
- config.xml: [config.xml](https://gist.github.com/adobi/eed2c67206eabcd23045)

- IndexController: [IndexController](https://gist.github.com/adobi/eb2ce0d172914f0bc95f)

- index.phtml: [index.phtml](https://gist.github.com/adobi/69ae34d33e0a30cf43f6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not expert in angular app but as per as my understand,You want to *send all angular requests* with prefix `angular-app` in your url.

So,you need to **create new custom router**. To understand the custom route,Follow the below link.

- [inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-router-in-magento/)
- [Atwix](https://www.atwix.com/magento/create-custom-router/)

For your case, using `controller_front_init_routers` add custom router at system by `$front->addRouter('addangularapp',$this);` on function `initControllerRouters` of class  *ModuleNameSpace_ModuleName_Controller_Router*

> ```
> <!--  define route -->
> <frontend>
>   <routers>
>       <angularapp> <!--  router identifier -->
>           <use>standard</use>
>           <args>
>               <modules>
>                   <module>ModuleNameSpace_ModuleName</module>
>                   <frontName>angularapp</frontName>
>               </modules>
>           </args>
>       </angularapp>
>   </routers>
> </frontend>
> <global>
>   <!-- event for add a router -->
>   <events>
>       <controller_front_init_routers>
>           <observers> 
>           <add_angularapp_route>  <!-- observer identifier -->
>               <class>ModuleNameSpace_ModuleName_Controller_Router</class>
>               <method>initControllerRouters</method>
>           </add_angularapp_route> 
>           </observers>
>       </controller_front_init_routers>
>   </events>
> </global>
> ```

Then at `match()` *validate and modify http request* (Zend_Controller_Request_Http). and if request have contain `angular-app` then it internally set `IndexController` as `controller` as ,`indexAction` as  *request action*  and *set your module as request module*.

```
$request->setModuleName('YOURROUTE') 
            ->setControllerName('index')
            ->setActionName('index');
```

**Controller code may like:**

```
<?php
class ModuleNameSpace_ModuleName_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract{
    /**
     * Initialize Controller Router
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */

    public function initControllerRouters($observer){
        $front=$observer->getEvent()->getFront();
        $front->addRouter('addangularapp',$this);

    }


    /* validate and modify the  request
     *  Params Zend_Controller_Request_Htt
     */
    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request){

        /* If Magento Magento is not install then 
         * redirect to installer url
         */
        If(!Mage::isInstalled()):
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
                ->sendResponse();
                 exit;

        endif;
        $requestPathInfo=trim($request->getPathInfo(),'/');
        Mage::log('aaa'.$requestPathInfo.'StoreId'.Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(), null, 'logfile.log');
        /* check -review-form not exit
         * then immediate return false
         */ 
        if(strpos($requestPathInfo,'angular-app')==false):
            return  false;
        endif;

        /* get productut from url 
            by  substr   
         */
        $producturl=str_replace('angular-app','',$requestPathInfo);

        $condition=new Varien_Object(array('product_url'=>$producturl,
            'continue'=>true));

        Mage::dispatchEvent('angular_app_controller_router_match_before', array(
                'router'    => $this,
                'condition' => $condition
        ));


        if($condition->getRedirectUrl()){
            Mage::app()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect($condition->getReDirectUrl())
                ->sendResponse();
            $request->setDispatched(true);
            return true;
        }

        if(!$condition->getContinue()){
            return  false;
        }


        $request->setModuleName('YOURROUTE') 
            ->setControllerName('index')
            ->setActionName('index')
        ->setParam('customparam', $requestPathInfo);
        $request->setAlias(
                Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                $requestPathInfo
        );


        return  true;

    }


}
```

**Note:** code is not tested.

same concet havec in https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/70619/4564 answer