# Rewrite ?cat= to seo friendly URL

Tags: magento-1.9, php, layered-navigation, url-rewrite, seo

(Magento) On a category page I can filter products by other categories using the ?cat=... parameter. This works just fine (In combination with Amasty improved navigation). But I would like to make the URL SEO friendly. Now my URL looks like:

```
https://sitedomain/brands/sony?cat=251
```

Explained:

"brands" is a category containing subcategories for all my brands.

"sony" (example) is a sub category of "brands" containing all Sony products.

"cat 251" is a category named "cameras" with a different parent (so not a sub category of "brands" or "Sony")

This URL shows me all Sony camera's, so that's just fine. But I would the URL to be:

```
https://sitedomain/brands/sony/cameras
or if that is not possible something like:
https://sitedomain/brands/sony/filter/cameras
```

I have no idea how to start. My approach was creating a module that triggers a URL rewrite as soon as the cat parameter exists. But I had no luck at all so far. So is this even possible? And if so, please point me into the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are one extension for it.

[Layered Navigation SEO](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/layered-navigation-seo.html)

Find Git hub [link](https://github.com/caciobanu/improved-magento-layered-navigation) for that extension.

**In your case you have to create custom route like Mage_Cms module.**

Refer this [Answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/70619/45103). [Git module](https://github.com/devamitbera/magento-stackexchange/tree/master/Rewrite%20review%20url%20-MSE-69682) to start.

Comment: Thank you. I have no doubt this plugin works with a clean magento install. But as I mentioned I use Amasty Improved Navigation. Unfortunately these modules do not work together. Besides that, this module has way to many functions for what I need. I only need to rewrite ?cat=.

Comment: @Tober answer updated. Its not exact answer for you but can be helpful to start.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I haven't implemented it yet, but I think this will help me a lot. If this (in a few days) turns out to be a good help/solution I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on product and/or category fluctuation and/or their count, it might be easiest to insert rewrite (without redirection) rules (by code) for every possible category combination.